# Digg Button Counter Not Working

Tags: javascript, digg

I really don't understand why the digg button counter is not working. It's pretty straight forward but..

The page is here: http://hockey-community.com/ if you look at my code I did exactly what they explained here: http://about.digg.com/downloads/button/smart

It just stays at 0.

Anyone had the same problem? Thanks for your help!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submitted URL ends with a `/`, the one in your source does not:

If you do:

```
<a class="DiggThisButton DiggMedium" href="http://digg.com/submit?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhockey-community.com/"></a>
```

it will show the correct number.

Comment: Wow would never think about that. Amazing, thanks a lot. It worked on my local machine.